# OData gives result only after making a web API request

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have created an Odata in web Api 2

I am adding routes like

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "odata",
            model: GetModel()
        );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I am getting a strange result.

If I hit the OData service first (after a building/publishing) it is showing the below image.
[image]

But if I hit an api request first and making the OData request next,

then I am getting the expected JSON.

In short an OData request works only after making an API request.

Can anyone say what would be reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

[Order matters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2014/12/17/web-api-odata-v4-pitfalls-and-lessons-learned.aspx). Try moving the OData config after the Web API config:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    ); 

config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: "odata",
        model: GetModel()
    );
```

If you don't have any regular Web API controllers, eliminate the call to `MapHttpRoute` entirely.